# Separating Containers: CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple question but just wanted to see if people use a different way that has more merit to it.  When I create a webpage, I start with the structure, usually the structure starts with about 5 main divs (top container, second container, ...., bottom container etc.).

To separate these containers, I usually set a margin on the bottom and top.  Does this have any cons to it?  Or is this how generally people separate containers?

Comment: This is really subjective! One downside is that background images won't fill in margins, which could be negative if you want container panels that touch with no gap in between, and also have different backgrounds. In that case you could remove the margins or use padding instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just glad I wasn't doing something wrong....a side question that is completely off topic, I'm not a noobie in creating websites, but what does the html{} tag do for css?  I always used html, body{margin:0;} to get rid of that extra space, but what is the difference between body and html in terms of css?

Comment: The `html` element is just another container. From a css perspective it's pretty much like any `div`.

Comment: @Hans `body` is a child of `html`.

Comment: Good shout—totally, meant that. Couldn't edit comment, so deleted.